# Create JAR file of a specific package in a multi-package project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, package, jetbrains-ide

I understand how to create a JAR file when there is only a single package in a Java project but don't know how to create a JAR file when there are multiple packages in a Java project.

I have a sample project with the following structure:
[image: Project Structure]

I have two packages which you can see in the picture i.e.

- academy.learnprogramming
- academy.ujjwal

I want to create a jar file for the classes which are in the `academy.ujjwal` package. I tried multiple ways from the Artifacts option but not sure how to do it right.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually uncommon to create jar file from command, [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/), [Gradle](https://gradle.org) like build tools are used but you can try following command.

```
jar cvp filename.jar /path/to/classes

 jar cvf  learnprogramming.jar src/academy.learnprogramming
 jar cvp abc.jar src/academy.ujjwal
```

Comment: `jar cvf abc.jar src/academy/ujjwal` This command creates a jar file but it's not like I intended. It is not similar to Build Artifact.
Also, when I try to import this jar file it doesn't work.
It could have been better if I can know what specific steps I need to follow for IntelliJ to create a jar from a package

Comment: you can follow [multi module project](https://medium.com/macoclock/how-create-multi-module-project-in-intellij-on-macos-50f07e52b7f9) article.